# « Elle s'est rendu destinataire d'une lettre » ou « elle s'est rendue » ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé, verbes-pronominaux

Word me corrige. Il me dicte que "elle s'est rendu destinataire d'une lettre" sans E pour Rendu.

Je trouve ça bizarre. Quelqu'un  m'explique s'il vous plaît.

Comment: Pour commencer, as-tu essayé d'isoler la phrase, pour être sûr qu'il comprenne bien la structure de la phrase ?

Comment: Oui la phrase entière simplifiée et réduite est "elle s'est rendue destinataire d'une lettre".  Je ne vois pas ce que je peux faire de plus ??

Answer (score 2):

Concernant les verbes pronominaux, il y a en effet une [exception](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-des-verbes-pronominaux-188.php):

> ### Les cas de non-accord
>
> 1. Le participe passé ne s'accorde pas lorsque C.O.D. suit le verbe.
>
>    Exemples : *Ils se sont lav**é** les mains. / Ils se sont écri**t** des lettres./ Ils se sont répart**i** tous les billets.*
> 2. Le participe passé ne s'accorde pas lorsque le verbe pronominal réfléchi ou réciproque admet un C.O.I.
>      Les participes passés des verbes suivants sont invariables :
>      se plaire, se complaire, se déplaire, se rire, se convenir, se nuire, se mentir, s'en vouloir, se ressembler, se sourire, se suffire, se survivre.
>
>    Exemples : *Ils se sont pl**u**. / Ils se sont dépl**u** dans cet appartement. / Elles se sont r**i** de son erreur.*

Comment: Mais est-ce que « se rendre destinataire » est bien un verbe pronominal ?

Comment: @Gilles Le verbe est "se rendre" + COD: Elle s'est rendu quoi ? Destinataire d'une lettre. Le pronom réfléchi fait parti du verbe, il est donc pronominal.